# XML reading the last entry from the file in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I want to read the last entry of the xml file and get its value. Here is **my xml file**

```
<TestSuite>
  <TestCase>
    <name>tcname1</name>
    <total>1</total>
    <totalpass>0</totalpass>
    <totalfail>0</totalfail>
    <totalerror>1</totalerror>
  </TestCase>
  <TestCase>
    <name>tcname2</name>
    <total>1</total>
    <totalpass>0</totalpass>
    <totalfail>0</totalfail>
    <totalerror>1</totalerror>
  </TestCase>
</TestSuite>
```

I want to get the `<total>` , `<totalpass>`,`<totalfail>` and `<totalerror>` value in the last tag of the file. I have tried this code to do that.

```
import xmltodict
with open(filename) as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
    length=len(doc['TestSuite']['TestCase'])
    tp=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase'][length-1]['totalpass']
    tf=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase'][length-1]['totalfail']
    te=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase'][length-1]['totalerror']
    total=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase'][length-1]['total']
```

This works for the xml with 2 or more testcase tags in xml files , But fails with this error for the file with only one testcase tag .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HTMLReportGenerationFromXML.py", line 52, in <module>
    tp=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase'][length-1]['totalpass']
KeyError: 4 .
```

Because instead of the  count , it is taking the subtag (  etc value as length). Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want the last one, you can use negative indices to retrieve it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse('test.xml')

# collect all the test cases
test_cases = [test_case for test_case in tree.findall('TestCase')]

# Pull data from the last one
last = test_cases[-1]
total = last.find('total').text
totalpass = last.find('totalpass').text
totalfail = last.find('totalfail').text
totalerror = last.find('totalerror').text

print total,totalpass,totalfail,totalerror
```

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't I do t his in the first place! Use xpath.

The first example involves processing the xml file with just one TestCase element, the second with two of them. The key point is to use the xpath `last` selector.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('temp.xml')
>>> last_TestCase = tree.xpath('.//TestCase[last()]')[0]
>>> for child in last_TestCase.iterchildren():
...     child.tag, child.text
... 
('name', 'tcname2')
('total', '1')
('totalpass', '0')
('totalfail', '0')
('totalerror', '1')
>>> 
>>> tree = etree.parse('temp_2.xml')
>>> last_TestCase = tree.xpath('.//TestCase[last()]')[0]
>>> for child in last_TestCase.iterchildren():
...     child.tag, child.text
... 
('name', 'tcname1')
('reason', 'reason')
('total', '2')
('totalpass', '0')
('totalfail', '0')
('totalerror', '2')
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. But it still fails the xml has only one tag like this.        
<TestSuite>
<TestCase>
<name>tcname1</name>
<reason>reason</reason>
<total>2</total>
<totalpass>0</totalpass>
<totalfail>0</totalfail>
<totalerror>2</totalerror>
</TestCase>
</TestSuite>

Comment: Now I understand (I think).

Comment: I think that the problem lies in the type of `doc['TestSuite']['TestCase']`. It could be either a `list` or an `OrderedDict`

Comment: @floatingpurr: Exactly. It's horrible.

Comment: Yes, it's strange

Comment: Please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of your error is that with `xmltidict` `doc['TestSuite']['TestCase']` is a list just for long XMLs

```
>>> type(doc2['TestSuite']['TestCase']) # here doc2 is more than one-entry long XML file 
>>> list
```

but it is just a kind of dictionary for a one-entry long file:

```
>>> type(doc['TestSuite']['TestCase']) # doc is one-entry long 
>>> collections.OrderedDict
```

That's the reason. You could try to manage the issue in the following way:

```
 import xmltodict
 with open(filename) as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

    if type(doc['TestSuite']['TestCase']) == list:    
        tp=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase'][length-1]['totalpass']

        tf=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase'][length-1]['totalfail']

        te=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase'][length-1]['totalerror']

        total=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase'][length-1]['total']

   else: # you have just a dict here
        tp=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase']['totalpass']

        tf=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase']['totalfail']

        te=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase']['totalerror']

        total=doc['TestSuite']['TestCase']['total']
```

Otherwise, you can use another library for the XML parsing.

...let me know if it helps!

Comment: Good! :) feel free to accept that answer, if you liked it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this this works for me

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
tree = ET.parse('temp.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print root
total=[]
totalpass=[]
totalfail=[]
totalerror=[]
for test in root.findall('TestCase'):
    total.append(test.find('total').text)
    totalpass.append(test.find('totalpass').text)
    totalfail.append(test.find('totalfail').text)
    totalerror.append(test.find('totalerror').text)
length=len(total)
print total[length-1],totalpass[length-1],totalfail[length-1],totalerror[length-1]
```

This one works for me